# PhpStorm type hinting array of objects fails after testing with is_array

Tags: php, autocomplete, phpstorm, type-hinting

I am having trouble getting Phpstorm type hints working on arrays of objects when I test the array with is_array() before iterating over the array.

Can anyone shed some light on why is_array() removes the type hinting of the objects?

```
$test = new Test();
$testers = $test->getAll();

// Type hinting WORKS for $test
foreach($testers as $test) {
    $test->getId(); // Type hinting works
}

// Type hinting does NOT work for $test
if(is_array($testers)) {
    foreach($testers as $test) {
        $test->getId(); // Type hinting does NOT work
    }
}
```

I can get type hinting to work if I add type hint comment where the array is retrieved, but this is undesirable, as I would prefer Phpstorm to use the object method return type hint info instead of having to specify it all the time:

Adding this works even when is_array is present
    /** @var Tester[] $testers */
    $testers = $test->getAll();

Test class code in case anyone wants to run the example:

```
class Tester {
    private $id;
    private $name;

    public function __construct($id, $name) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * @return Integer
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return String
     */
    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

}

class Test {
    /**
     * @return tester[]
     */
    public function getAll() {
        $testers = array(
            new Tester(1, 'Bob'),
            new Tester(2, 'Jane'),
            new Tester(3, 'Tim')
        );
        return $testers;
    }
}
```

Comment: But your `getAll()` function always returns an array, why would you need to test it?

Comment: In this example it always returns array, in my real world code this is not always the case.

Comment: Then, imo, your docblock type hint is wrong and should have an alternation, i.e. `@return tester[]|null`.

Comment: @Jack I don't think that really answers the question or helps as the questions relates to why is_array loses the type hinting. Even if I change the docblock it doesn't solve the issue

Comment: You're right, but this is the *comment* section is it not? It does seem to be a bug with PhpStorm, though; somehow the generic-array deduction has higher priority over the docblock.

Comment: Yes this is the comments and I appreciate you taking a look at the questions. Thanks for pointing out the incorrect docblock.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68789/discussion-between-baxny-and-jack).

Comment: Yes, `is_array()` and other similar standard functions (as well as constructions like `instance of`) will override deducted/typehinted type. In this particular case it should not do this as `tester[]` is declaration of an array anyway. I may only suggest to submit a ticket to JB Issue Trakcer at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI (but check for any existing tickets first).